# In Portfolio.Return coding

Tags: r

I do my portfolio analysis and I want to calculate Return.portfolio but I do not get logic behind rebalance_on part which is part of code. I can choose daily, monthly or yearly but I do not know according what I should choode. My dataset covers 3 years period of time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from a new contributor to another your question isn't following Stack overflow guidelines. Always check if there are vignettes or examples of a function before asking a question.  It is helpful if you use a reproducible coding example.

Anyway, I will try to help since I study finance.

I'm assuming your question is about `return.portfolio()` form the PerformanceAnalytics package. Without a code I can only guess.

The argument 'rebalance_on' is used to periodically rebalance the number of assets in your portfolio to maintain an equal weight portfolio.

The `return.portfolio()` function vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/vignettes/portfolio_returns.pdf) has explanations on portfolio return calculations and the function usage.